# switching images dynamically on jframe

Tags: java, swing

I have an assignment to create a GUI that switches images when a menu item is selected (ex. file, new picture) and also contains buttons for zooming in and out on the images. When I try switching images with my code, the image only partly loads. When I minimize the window and then reopen it, the image is fully loaded. I'm wondering why this is happening.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImageZoom extends JPanel {

 private Image image;
 int x, y;
 private JButton zoomIn;
 private JButton zoomOut;
 private JMenuBar bar;
 private JMenu file;
 private JMenuItem choosePic = new JMenuItem("New Picture");
 private String pics[] = {"waterfall.jpg", "mountains.jpg"};
 private int picIndex = 1;
 int imageHeight = getHeight();
 int imageWidth = getWidth();
 int zoom = 1;
 Image images[] = new Image[2];

 public ImageZoom() {

  try {
   images[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("waterfall.jpg"));
   images[1] = ImageIO.read(new File("mountains.jpg"));
  } catch (IOException e) {}

  zoomIn = new JButton("+");
  zoomOut = new JButton("-");

 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 bar = new JMenuBar();
 file = new JMenu("File");  
 file.add(choosePic);
 bar.add(file);

 choosePic.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == choosePic) {

     repaint();

    }

   }
  }); 

  zoomIn.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == zoomIn) {     

      if (zoom < 6) {
      zoom += 1;
      repaint();

     }

    }

   }

  });


  zoomOut.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == zoomOut) {    

     if (zoom > 1) {
     zoom -= 1;
     repaint();

     }

    }     

   }

  });  

 }

 public JPanel getButtonPanel () {

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.add(zoomIn);
  panel.add(zoomOut);

  return panel;

 }

 public Image getImage() {

  try {
  image = ImageIO.read(new File(pics[picIndex % 2]));
  picIndex++;

  }
  catch (IOException e){}
  return image;

 }

 protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {

  imageHeight = getHeight() * zoom;
  imageWidth = getWidth() * zoom;

  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(getImage(), 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, null);

 }

 public void createJFrame () {

 JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 

 ImageZoom imgZoom = new ImageZoom();

 frame.setJMenuBar(bar);  
 frame.add(imgZoom);
 frame.add(getButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setSize(650, 650); 
 frame.setResizable(false);
 frame.setVisible(true); 

 }

}

class Test {

 public static void main (String[] args) {

 ImageZoom zoom = new ImageZoom();
 zoom.createJFrame();

 } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, you should just be using a `JLabel` and calling its `setIcon` method to switch the images. You could dynamically scale the images as required (just maintain a reference to the original)

## Problem #1

You should be passing `this` to `drawImage`, this will allow the component to act as the `ImageObserver` and schedule additional reprints as required based on events from the image's state, which leads to

## Problem #2

You should not be calling `getImage` from within the `paintComponent` method, `paintComponent` could be called for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control or even know about and `paintComponent` should simply paint the current state of the component and never, ever try and change the state

**Side Note:** Instead of repeatedly trying to load the images, it would be better to load them once and continue to reuse the loaded reference